# Display xml in browser without warning message

Tags: html, xml

I have an xml file that I am displaying in an iframe, but it gives me a warning that "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

When I add style sheet information on this xml it will show only data inside of tag.

How can I show it in a normal way without warning message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try a JavaScript plug-in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366179/how-to-display-xml-in-a-html-page-as-a-collapsible-and-expandable-tree-using-jav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the XML file to .txt first.

XML files are supposed to be interpreted, not displayed in their raw form. (They don't need to; under normal circumstances, you can always see the XML source by clicking "View Source".) If you want to display a file as is, the file should be a plain text file.

Comment: No i also want to display this XML file in colored form.

Comment: You mean the same way as it's displayed in View Source?

Comment: Exactly! i want it to display in web page as it display in view source.

Comment: yes his solution  worked fine, but now expanding and collapsing has some problem in FF.

Comment: Now everything is working fine in IE and Chrome, but my java script code is not working  Mozilla.