# How to get XML Formatted text in a modal popup

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a Grid and a column in it open up a modal. I want to display XML in that modal which is stored as formatted string. I want it look like like a proper XML and it must collapse tags as well. How to do this ? I'm using Bootstrap 3, mvc5.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to iframe the xml data. Most browsers show the xml nicely formatted with collapse tags as well.

With a string you can do that as well like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wypyewvt/

Just add it in the `src` of the iframe with `src="data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,YOURCONTENT_HERE`.

Comment: But what my code returns to me is a string. Will be able to display that string in the iframe and still get nice XML view ?

Comment: Understood. But the output is not something that I want. My output must be XML with collapsible tags and not just mere text. Like this:

<PatientInformation>
<PatientID>142131</PatientID>                      <LastName>ABC</LastName>
<FirstName>XYZ</FirstName>
<Gender>F</Gender>
<DOB>12/12/1977</DOB>
</PatientInformation>

Comment: I see that it works different in different browsers, and also not very good in jsfiddle for some reason. I will try something different (although sometimes it does work in jsfiddle and sometimes it doesnt.. weird)

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you find a way. Meanwhile even I'm trying to find a way as you told.

Comment: Did you also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366179/how-to-display-xml-in-a-html-page-as-a-collapsible-and-expandable-tree-using-jav ?

Comment: Check this page: http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/DisplayXMLFileWithJavascript.html Looks very promising for you.